# Been fiddling around with trying to make this component more responsive in CSS with very little luck

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My issue is that the container named mst doesn't contain the bg class as it should. So I'm assuming it's something I'm truly overlooking in terms of margin, padding, or a display property. Further more is there another way of creating the component in a more mobile-friendly way? Thanks for any help in advance!

```css
 
 

}html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", Playfair Display, Sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--mainText);
  font-family: "Playfair Display" Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px #f5f5f5;
}

h2 {
  color: var(--secondaryText);
  font-family: "Playfair Display", Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px #b9b6b6;
}

p,
li,
span,
label,
input,
textarea {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color:grey;
}


.mst-ctn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 18.9rem;
  width: 1200px;
}
.sch-ctn {
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sch-header {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 0;
}

.sch-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 3em;
  width: 8em;
  border-radius: 4em;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 60px;
}

.bg-ctn {
  background-color: #f95356;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-ctn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(241, 240, 240), rgb(195, 203, 211)) no-repeat
    center/1px 70%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 850px;
  height: 340px;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 110px 40px 0px 20px;
}

.left p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right {
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 85px 0px 50px 0px;
}
.right p {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.right div {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mst-ctn">
      <div class="sch-ctn">
        <div class="sch-header"><h2>Schedule a walk</h2></div>
      </div>

      <div class="bg-ctn">
        <div class="flex-ctn">
          <div class="left">
            <p><b>Meet and Greet</b></p>

            <p>20min | Free</p>
          </div>

          <div class="right">
            <p>
              This is a free visit done before any services start. It is for
              everyone to get acquainted, for you to show us your pet’s routine,
              etc. and for us to answer any questions ...
            </p>
            <div>
              <form action="">
                <button class="sch-btn" type="submit">Book Now</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want it responsive don't use fixed pixel values for sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Paulie_D commented: "If you want it responsive don't use fixed pixel values for sizes". For more info about CSS units of length, check out [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp). In the code below, I commented-out any redundant CSS and changed many of the fixed-width values to relative values. Please let me know if you still have any questions.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", Playfair Display, Sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--mainText);
  font-family: "Playfair Display" Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 5em;
}

h2 {
  color: var(--secondaryText);
  font-family: "Playfair Display", Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px #b9b6b6;
  font-size: 3em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p,
li,
span,
label,
input,
textarea {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* WRAPS ENTIRE PAGE */

.mst-ctn {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* position: relative; */
  margin: 0 5vw;
  /* Changed "18.9rem" --> "5vw" for responsiveness. */
  /* width: 1200px; */
}


/* MAKES A CONTAINER RESPONSIVE */

.ctn {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* HEADER CONTAINER */

.sch-ctn {
  /* display: flex; */
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  /* You can add a margin-top or padding-top here if you would like. */
}


/*.sch-header {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 0;
}*/


/* MAIN CONTENT CONTAINER */

.bg-ctn {
  background-color: #f95356;
}

.flex-ctn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /* Responsive Vertical Alignment */
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(241, 240, 240), rgb(195, 203, 211)) no-repeat center / 1px 70%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  /* width: 850px; */
  /* height: 340px; */
  text-align: center;
  /* Responsive Horizontal Alignment */
}

.sch-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: ;
  /* This doesn't do anything. */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 3em;
  width: 8em;
  border-radius: 4em;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 15px;
}


/* LEFT COLUMN */

.left {
  color: whitesmoke;
  /* I like this color! */
  width: 50%;
  /* 350px --> 50% */
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.left p {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* RIGHT COLUMN */

.right {
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 50%;
  /* 350px --> 50% */
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.right p {
  padding: 0px 10%;
}


/*.right div {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="mst-ctn">

  <div class="ctn sch-ctn">
    <!--<div class="sch-header">-->
    <h2>Schedule a walk</h2>
    <!--</div>-->
  </div>

  <div class="ctn bg-ctn">
    <div class="flex-ctn">
      <div class="left">
        <p><b>Meet and Greet</b></p>
        <p>20min | Free</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>
          This is a free visit done before any services start. It is for everyone to get acquainted, for you to show us your pet’s routine, etc. and for us to answer any questions ...
        </p>
        <div>
          <form action="">
            <button class="sch-btn" type="submit">Book Now</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this work's perfectly! Also thank you for the tips in the CSS as well.